# Returning a list of nearest neighbors from KNN

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use a KNN model to show the closest related brands to brand X. I have read in my data and transposed it so that the format is like this:

```
          User1     User2     User3     User4     User5
Brand1    1         0         0         0         1
Brand2    0         0         0         1         1
Brand3    0         0         1         1         1
Brand4    1         1         1         0         1
Brand5    0         0         0         1         1
```

I've then defined my model:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine', algorithm='brute')
model_knn.fit(df_mini)
```

Then I use the following code to list the nearest 5 brands to a randomly selected brand:

```
query_index = np.random.choice(df_mini.shape[0])
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(df_mini.iloc[query_index, :].values.reshape(1, -1), n_neighbors = 6)

for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):
    if i == 0:
        print ('Recommendations for {0}:\n'.format(df_mini.index[query_index]))
    else:
        print ('{0}: {1}, with distance of {2}:'.format(i, df_mini.index[indices.flatten()[i]], distances.flatten()[i]))
```

Returning sample results like this:

> ```
> Recommendations for BRAND_X:
>
> 1: BRAND_a, with distance of 1.0:
> 2: BRAND_b, with distance of 1.0:
> 3: BRAND_c, with distance of 1.0:
> 4: BRAND_d, with distance of 1.0:
> 5: BRAND_e, with distance of 1.0:
> ```

All my results are showing all brands with a distance of 1.0, where have i gone wrong in my code for this to be the case? I have tried increasing the size of the sample data and this remains the same, which makes me feel it's a code error rather than a data quirk?

EDIT: Here is a fuller sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df.head())

df_mini = df[:5000]
df_mini = df_mini.transpose()
df_mini = df_mini.drop('UserID',axis=0)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine', algorithm='brute')
model_knn.fit(df_mini)

query_index = np.random.choice(df_mini.shape[0])
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(df_mini.iloc[query_index, :].values.reshape(1, -1), n_neighbors = 6)

for i in range(0, len(distances.flatten())):
    if i == 0:
        print ('Recommendations for {0}:\n'.format(df_mini.index[query_index]))
    else:
        print ('{0}: {1}, with distance of {2}:'.format(i, df_mini.index[indices.flatten()[i]], distances.flatten()[i]))
```

Sample data file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19KRJDGrsLNpDD0WNAz4be76O66fGmQtJ

Comment: Could you please add more code, so that others can run your code and help you debugging it?

Comment: @TimH Sure thing, I've added a larger block of my current code.

Comment: Could you also add some sample data, so that we are able to run the same scenario?

Comment: @TimH Added this to the bottom of my question, and here (https://drive.google.com/open?id=19KRJDGrsLNpDD0WNAz4be76O66fGmQtJ)